# ¿Como puedo incluir elementos scripts dentro del editor Tynimce?

Tags: javascript, script, tinymce

Estoy usando el editor Tinymce, y quiero poder incluir ciertos scripts dentro de los documentos. No los coloco defrente en la plantilla, ya que son scripts que irán variando de acuerdo a la página. El problema es que cuando los coloco en el editor, Tynimce los elimina.

¿Se puede cambiar la configuración de Tynimce para que no borre mis script?

Actualmente lo tengo configurado así.

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    var editor_config = {
        path_absolute : "/",
        selector: "textarea.my-editor",
        plugins: [
        "autosave",
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media | restoredraft",
        relative_urls: false,
        autosave_interval: "5s",
        file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
        var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
        var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

        var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
        if (type == 'image') {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
        } else {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
        }

        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file : cmsURL,
            title : 'Filemanager',
            width : x * 0.8,
            height : y * 0.8,
            resizable : "yes",
            close_previous : "no"});
        }
    };

    tinymce.init(editor_config);

    
    

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Por si alguien más tiene este mismo problema, ya encontré la solución.
En la variable editor_config, agregue la siguiente propiedad.

```
extended_valid_elements : "script[class|src|type]"
```

Y luego de eso puedo escibir los script, con los atributos class, src y type sin ningún problema.